# Sobreposição de texto ao alterar propriedade height

Tags: html, css, height

Não consigo igualar  a altura do ítem "9". Quando faço isso com a propriedade height, o texto fica sobreposto.

[image]

```css
table{
  border-spacing: 10px;
  
}


td{
  
   vertical-align: top;     
   padding: 5px;
   white-space: nowrap;
   
   
 }

 td.test{
  min-width: 40px;
  min-height: 100px;
  
 }
 

p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  
  
  }

  

  tfoot {
    max-width: 980px;
    text-align: right;
    margin: auto;
  
    
  }
  .someclassname { height: 2px; }
```

```html
<td class = "test" valign="bottom" align="left" colspan="2">
        <p  style="line-height: 10px">
          <font face="arial" size=2> <b>&#160;09</b></font>
          <font size="1"> VALOR DOS JUROS E/OU ENCARGOS
            <BR>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160; DL-1025/69

          </font>
        </p>
      </td>

      <td align="right">
        <font face="arial" size="2"><b>{{ darf.valorJurosEncargos }}&#160;</b></font>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td  valign="top" align="left" colspan="2">
        <font face="arial" size=2><b>&#160;10</b></font>
        <font face="arial" size="1"> VALOR TOTAL</font>
        <br>
      </td>
      <td align="right" width="18">
        <font face="arial" size="2"><b>{{ darf.valorTotal }}</b></font>
        <br>

      </td>
```

Comment: Vc quer que as linhas tenham a mesma altura? Isso não é bom para tabelas, porque a fluidez do texto dentro da célula é que define a altura.

Comment: Não deu para entender exatamente o que vc precisa.... Pq não aumenta a largura da tabela para ficar tudo em um linha sem quebrar a linha quando o texto é maior

Comment: Sim, mas o texto encavala quando deixo as alturas iguais.

Comment: As colunas não podem ser muito diferentes na largura